# ¿Cómo hago que un código de Pila guarde varias variables en una estructura?

Tags: c, pilas, estructuras

Estoy tratando de modificar un código de pila para que en su lugar pida varios datos que podamos almacenar, no llevo mucho tiempo aprendiendo C por lo que se me ha dificultado un poco hacer que una pila en vez de almacenar una simple variable almacene varias variables en una estructura, aunque llevo unos cuantos días tratando de hacerlo, el código original es este:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
struct pilaNodo{
    int datos;
    struct pilaNodo *siguientePtr; // apuntador a stacknodo
};
typedef struct pilaNodo PILANODO;
typedef PILANODO *PILANODOPTR;
void push(PILANODOPTR *cimaPtr, int); //función push
int pop(PILANODOPTR *cimaPtr); //función pop
int vacio(PILANODOPTR);
void imprimirPila(PILANODOPTR);
void instrucciones(void);

int main(){
    
    PILANODOPTR pilaPtr = NULL;
    int eleccion, valor;
    
    instrucciones();
    printf("? ");
    scanf("%d",&eleccion);
    
    while (eleccion!= 3){
        switch(eleccion){
            case 1:
                printf("Escribe un número entero: ");
                scanf("%d",&valor);
                push(&pilaPtr,valor);
                imprimirPila(pilaPtr);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!vacio(pilaPtr))
                printf("El valor quitado es: %d. \n", pop(&pilaPtr));
                imprimirPila(pilaPtr);
                break;
            default:
                printf("elección invalida \n\n");
                instrucciones();
                break;
        }
        printf("? ");
        scanf("%d",&eleccion);
    }
    printf("Programa finalizado \n");
    return 0;
}

void instrucciones(void){
printf("Pon tu elección: \n"
        "1 para ponerle un valor a la pila\n"
        "2 para quitarle un valor a la pila\n"
        "3 para finalizar el programa\n");
}

void push(PILANODOPTR *cimaPtr, int informacion){ //función push, cimaPtr es pilaPtr en el switch e informacion es valor en el switch
    
    PILANODOPTR nuevoPtr;
    
    nuevoPtr =malloc(sizeof(PILANODO));
    if (nuevoPtr !=NULL){
        nuevoPtr-> datos =informacion;
        nuevoPtr -> siguientePtr= *cimaPtr;
        *cimaPtr=nuevoPtr;
    }
    else
    printf("%d no fue insertado a la pila. No hay memoria disponible. \n",informacion);
    
}
int  pop(PILANODOPTR *cimaPtr) //función pop
{
    PILANODOPTR temporalPtr;
    int popValor;
    temporalPtr=*cimaPtr;
    popValor=(*cimaPtr)->datos;
    *cimaPtr=(*cimaPtr)->siguientePtr;
    free(temporalPtr);
    return popValor;
    
}
void imprimirPila(PILANODOPTR actualPtr){
    if(actualPtr==NULL)
        printf("La pila está vacía.\n\n");
    else{
        printf("La pila es: \n");
        while(actualPtr != NULL){
            printf("%d-->", actualPtr->datos);
            actualPtr=actualPtr->siguientePtr;
        }
    printf("NULL\n\n");
    
    }
}
int vacio(PILANODOPTR cimaPtr){
    return cimaPtr==NULL;
}
```

Lo más cerca que he llegado hasta este punto es:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
struct datos{ //estructura de los datos que ahora le quiero agregar
    char nombre[15];
    int edad;
    long celular;
};
struct pilaNodo{
    struct datos d;// estructura anidada
    struct pilaNodo *siguientePtr; // apuntador a stacknodo
}d1;// variable de la estructura
typedef struct datos DATOS;// declaración de la estructura datos
typedef DATOS datos1;// creación de "datos1"
typedef struct pilaNodo PILANODO;
typedef PILANODO *PILANODOPTR;
void push(PILANODOPTR *cimaPtr, PILANODO); //función push
int pop(PILANODOPTR *cimaPtr); //función pop
int vacio(PILANODOPTR);
void imprimirPila(PILANODOPTR);
void instrucciones(void);

int main(){
    
    PILANODOPTR pilaPtr = NULL;
    int eleccion;
    PILANODO d;
    
    instrucciones();
    printf("? ");
    scanf("%d",&eleccion);
    
    while (eleccion!= 3){
        switch(eleccion){
            case 1:
                printf("Escribe tu nombre: ");
                scanf("%c",d1.d.nombre);
                printf("Escribe tu edad: ");
                scanf("%d",&d1.d.edad);
                printf("Escribe tu número de celular: ");
                scanf("%ln",&d1.d.celular);
                push(&pilaPtr,d); //WARNING: d no se inicia cuando es usado aquí
                imprimirPila(pilaPtr);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!vacio(pilaPtr))
                printf("El valor quitado es: %d. \n", pop(&pilaPtr));
                imprimirPila(pilaPtr);
                break;
            default:
                printf("elección invalida \n\n");
                instrucciones();
                break;
        }
        printf("? ");
        scanf("%d",&eleccion);
    }
    printf("Programa finalizado \n");
    return 0;
}

void instrucciones(void){
printf("Pon tu elección: \n"
        "1 para ponerle un valor a la pila\n"
        "2 para quitarle un valor a la pila\n"
        "3 para finalizar el programa\n");
}

void push(PILANODOPTR *cimaPtr, d);{ //marca error, tiene tipos conflictivos y busca un identificador
    
    PILANODOPTR nuevoPtr;
    
    nuevoPtr =malloc(sizeof(PILANODO));
    if (nuevoPtr !=NULL){
        nuevoPtr-> d =DATOS;
        nuevoPtr -> siguientePtr= *cimaPtr;
        *cimaPtr=nuevoPtr;
    }
    else
    printf("%d no fue insertado a la pila. No hay memoria disponible. \n",informacion);
    
}
int  pop(PILANODOPTR *cimaPtr) //función pop
{
    PILANODOPTR temporalPtr;
    DATOS popValor;
    temporalPtr=*cimaPtr;
    popValor=(*cimaPtr)->d;
    *cimaPtr=(*cimaPtr)->siguientePtr;
    free(temporalPtr);
    return popValor; //marca error Datos es incompatible con int
    
}
void imprimirPila(PILANODOPTR actualPtr){
    if(actualPtr==NULL)
        printf("La pila está vacía.\n\n");
    else{
        printf("La pila es: \n");
        while(actualPtr != NULL){
            printf("%DATOS-->", actualPtr->d); //WARNING: d es asignado como entero
            actualPtr=actualPtr->siguientePtr;
        }
    printf("NULL\n\n");
    
    }
}
int vacio(PILANODOPTR cimaPtr){
    return cimaPtr==NULL;
}
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo eliminar los errores o si tan siquiera me acerqué a lo deseado?,¿o acaso necesito hacer otra cosa para lograr lo que deseo?. Cualquier tipo de ayuda y corrección se aprecia mucho para que pueda seguir aprendiendo, y muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer mi pregunta

Comment: Veo que tienes un jaleo bastante grande, por lo que te recomiendo hacer ejercicios de estructuras más sencillos para que cojas soltura con ello. Piensa que una estructura simplemente es una manera de agrupar información de una manera ordenada, en la que puedes acceder a la información a través de su identificador, por ejemplo: tu estructura `datos` tiene un `char`, un `int` y un `long`, por lo que para acceder a cualquiera de ellos basta con acceder a `datos.nombre`, datos.edad` o `datos.celular`. Para simplificar, es como trabajar con variables normales pero indicando el nombre de la `struct`